# Numbering the lines with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got a problem. I need to add lines in the table and give the numbered classes, like name_4, name_5 and so on using `javascript` or `jquery`.

```
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
        <button>Добавить</button>
        <input type="submit" value="Подтвердить">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class='name_1'>ФИО</td>
                <td class='subj1_1'>1-ый предмет</td>
                <td class='subj2_1'>2-ой предмет</td>
                <td class='subj3_1'>3-ий предмет</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class='name_2'>text</td>
                <td class='subj1_2'>text</td>
                <td class='subj2_2'>text</td>
                <td class='subj3_2'>text</td>
            </tr> 
        </table>
        </form>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("button").click(function(){
                var line = "<tr><td class='name'>Text</td><td class='subj1'></td><td class='subj2'></td><td class='subj3'></td></tr>"
                $("table").append(line)
                $("tr:last").hide()
                $("tr:last").fadeToggle(1000)
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the length of `tr` using `$("#tableId tr).length` and add 1 to it

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let getTRLength = $("#myTable tr").length + 1;
    var line = "<tr><td class='name_" + getTRLength + "'>Text</td><td class='subj1'></td><td class='subj2'></td><td class='subj3'></td></tr>"
    $("table").append(line)
    $("tr:last").hide()
    $("tr:last").fadeToggle(1000)
  });
});
```

```css
.name_3 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
  <button>Добавить</button>
  <input type="submit" value="Подтвердить">
  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td class='name_1'>ФИО</td>
      <td class='subj1_1'>1-ый предмет</td>
      <td class='subj2_1'>2-ой предмет</td>
      <td class='subj3_1'>3-ий предмет</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='name_2'>text</td>
      <td class='subj1_2'>text</td>
      <td class='subj2_2'>text</td>
      <td class='subj3_2'>text</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because you didn't specify the `button type attribute`. Always specify the `type` attribute for a `<button>` element. Different browsers use different default types for the `<button>` element.

If you use the `<button>` element in an HTML form, different browsers may submit different values. Use `<input>` to create buttons in an HTML form.

If your buttons are not to submit form data to a server, be sure to set their `type attribute` to button. Otherwise they will try to `submit` form data and to load the nonexistent response, possibly destroying the current state of the document.

```js
$( document ).ready( function() {
 $( 'button' ).click( function() {
  var line = "<tr><td class='name'>Text</td><td class='subj1'></td><td class='subj2'></td><td class='subj3'></td></tr>";
  $( 'table' ).append( line );
  $( 'tr:last' ).hide().fadeToggle( 1000 )
 } );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
 <button type="button">Добавить</button>
 <input type="submit" value="Подтвердить">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td class='name_1'>ФИО</td>
   <td class='subj1_1'>1-ый предмет</td>
   <td class='subj2_1'>2-ой предмет</td>
   <td class='subj3_1'>3-ий предмет</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class='name_2'>text</td>
   <td class='subj1_2'>text</td>
   <td class='subj2_2'>text</td>
   <td class='subj3_2'>text</td>
  </tr> 
 </table>
</form>
```